# quartz.net: how to add and remove jobs at runtime

Tags: quartz.net

I am using a windows service to run Quartz.NET jobs with the help of the Spring.NET integration.

I am facing the following two problems:

1. I am constantly adding / removing jobs (with new spring.net configurations for new business objects). That means that I need to stop the windows service and the running jobs each time.
2. Furthermore the jobs take a lot of time to execute, so it would be good to have several servers each executing the jobs which I configure at one central place.

How would you recommend implementing these 2 features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no way to do #1 without writing code to load the scheduler in a separate app domain and then managing the app domains yourself. This is not available in the Quartz.Net distribution, so you would have to do it yourself.

For item #2 you can set up clustered quartz servers, which would solve that problem. You will need to use a database store to be able to set up the schedulers to be clustered.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to set up the quartz clustered servers, another suggestion is to roll your own simple queue based architecture.  Have a single lightweight scheduler service that pushes your jobs onto a queue (AWS/Azure queues work well) and then a pool of workers that can consume those jobs.  I faced similar issues with changing quartz schedules and found it easier to manage quartz when I didn't have to worry about my long running processes running in quartz threads.  Granted if you actually need to stop jobs once a change is requested this might not work for you.